# Equals overloading with multiple types gives a Operator '==' cannot be applied to

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, equals

Here an equals overloading

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    val string: String = ...

    override operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other != null) else { return false }
        if (other is MyClass && string == other.string) { return true }
        if (other is String && string == other) { return true }
        return false
    }
    ...
}
```

The idea is to be able to compare:

```
myClass1 = MyClass("ABCDEF")
myClass2 = MyClass("ABC123")

myClass1 == fsPath2  >> false
or
myClass1 == "ABC123" >> false
```

But the precompiled says: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'MyClass' and 'String'

Any idea?

Comment: I can't find it documented explicitly anywhere, but it appears that the Kotlin compiler will not allow two different types that don't inherit from each other to be compared with the `==` operator, but does allow it if you use `.equals()`.

Comment: There is an issue in Kotlin bug tracker about your case https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4071

Comment: @AndreiTanana that issue is closed and flagged "working as designed". You can look for some more info around there but this is how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid this can't work the way you want.

In order for equality to behave the way everyone expects, it has a very specific contract.  (The docs for the Kotlin [Any.equals()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html) method spell out all the necessary conditions, and the docs for the Java [Object.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method have a bit more info.)

One of the conditions is that the equality relation must be reversible: `a == b` if and only if `b == a`.  (In technical terms, the relation must be *symmetric*.)

But that's not true of your implementation:

- `myClass1.equals("ABCDEF")` returns true (from `MyClass`'s implementation of `equals()`), but
- `"ABCDEF".equals(myClass1)` returns false (from calling `String`'s implementation)

A system class like `String` doesn't know about your class, and there's no way to change its `equals()` implementation so it does.  So unfortunately there's no way to treat it as equal, without breaking the contract.

(You can probably imagine some of the subtle bugs that could cause: for example, a Set could hold both of those objects, or just one, depending on the order they happened to be added in…)

The compiler error you're getting is an indirect result of this: assuming the `equals()` contract holds, unrelated classes are *never* going to be treated as equal, so the compiler won't even let you try to compare them that way.

Because of the strict contract, you need to take great care when implementing `equals()`; as well symmetry, it's easy to break transitivity and/or consistency, and you need to override `hashCode()` to match.  See for example [these](https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-javas-equals-method-correctly/) [articles](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts).  (And even if you control both classes, it's still surprisingly tricky to get equality working between them; [this article](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) explains the issues rather well.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. I can understand your point of view @gidds but it has been not considerate the same way by Swift team. In Swift only the approach of functional signature account. So left:typeA == right:typeB works perfectly.

Comment: But it’s true than in swift operator overloading aren’t Any constrained.